# The tag curation workflow is unnecessarily cumbersome

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, privileges, tag-wiki

I found this discussion when I was trying to figure out why I couldn't improve a suggested tag wiki edit that had a typo in it:

[Allow 'improve' for Tag Wiki Edit Suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315999/273494)

> Tag wiki edit suggestions can be Improved, same as other posts.
>
> But you can only Improve a post if you would have the right to edit it unsupervised. For questions and answers, the requirement is the same as approving edits: 2000 reputation. For tag wikis, you can approve at 5000 reputation, but you need 20000 to make your own unsupervised edit.

I agree that I shouldn't be able to improve a suggested edit if I don't have the privilege to edit that content unsupervised. I think it's silly to force me to either reject a well-meaning addition of a tag wiki because it had a typo, approve a tag wiki with errors in it, or just leave them to languish in the queue.

It takes too much effort to create a description for a tag and it makes no sense that the reputation required to do it without supervision is so high compared to the reputation to create a tag out of thin air with no description of what it's intended to mean.

The workflow for curating tags is just bad, and the few people that care about making them useful get burnt out pretty quickly. Yeah, I typed this up in a fit of frustration, and my initial proposal wasn’t something I had thought through, so I’m changing it from a feature request to a discussion.

- If a suggested tag wiki has a typo but is otherwise OK, it takes way too long to correct on sites without many active 20k reviewers.
- There are no queues to review newly created tags to ensure they get meaningful wikis or are replaced with an existing tag.
- It’s nearly impossible to get a tag synonym approved without moderator intervention on some sites. People have the privilege to approve them, but never think to look to see what proposals they can vote on. Look at these dates:

  [image: The ELL pending tag synonym list showing synonyms from a decade ago with no votes]
- It’s difficult to pick good tags for a post because the full tag descriptions aren’t easy to display and search through while editing.
- As [Sonic mentioned in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398068/the-tag-curation-workflow-is-unnecessarily-cumbersome#comment1329028_398068):

  > Another issue: there is no public history of when a tag was created in the past and subsequently removed. What often happens is that many of these tags are discussed on meta and removed, and then recreated by users who don't know of the discussion.
- It's difficult for people asking questions to know which tags are the most appropriate when they might not know that word is a participle and not a gerund.

Tags can be really useful when properly curated. They group questions together to make suggestions for related questions more relevant. They make it easier to search for topics that are difficult to narrow down with just text. They make it easier to discover interesting questions to answer.

Comment: At the moment the best recourse/workaround for getting action on tag synonyms/merges is to raise them on the site's Meta for discussion, but that also relies on the site's mod team to be proactive and actually take actions requested and upvoted by community members. Incidentally, [that's what we do on Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-rename-request)

Comment: Another issue: there is no public history of when a tag was created in the past and subsequently removed. What often happens is that many of these tags are discussed on meta and removed, and then recreated by users who don't know of the discussion. While [it's not prudent to block every tag that's removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242624/377214), there should at least be a public history so that users can use that info to make tag block requests.

Comment: Suggesting appropriate tags during question editing might  be something actually useful AI could do given it can parse natural language.

Comment: My tag workflow is "Make a meta post. Wait for Bhargav Rao to fix everything."

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Concerning previous instance of tags, when I am interested in something like that, I use the queries like [the ones listed here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2024/3/11). (Of course, they are far from perfect - but it's at least something.) See also: [How can I query the Data Explorer for historical changes in posts' tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296890)